# formulario imagenes html5

Tags: html, laravel

Tengo un problema con un formulario en Laravel-Voyager, quería saber si es posible que al momento de enviar un formulario con imagenes si al incumplirse alguna de las reglas del request como (Required|Min|Max), este al volver al formulario no me elimine las imagenes que ya se habian colocado anteriormente

Aqui se ve que las imagenes se cargaron
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si por algun motivo el usuario olvida algun dato o no coloca la cantidad de caracteres necesarios, este no borre las imagenes del formulario
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

No conozco Laravel, pero te sugiero que intentes filtrar eso tambien a nivel de HTML.

Para los `textarea` el campo deberia ser así (lo pongo de forma mínima, tu debes adaptarlo a tu escenario con el resto de atributos que necesites):

```
<textarea minlength="20" required></textarea>
```

Para los input numéricos así:

```
<input type="number" min="20" required />
```

También existen el `maxlength` para los textarea y el `max` para los input numéricos. Tan solo aplícalo como creas conveniente.

Con eso consigues que html te lo filtre antes y espero que así evites la referencia a los archivos ya seleccionados para subir.

Comment: Si la herramienta voyager que se esta usando en este momento al colocar la configuracion al input lo hace tanto en el front como desde el backend, por eso la respuesta ser enviada desde el back al front borra, unicamente los campos de imagenes y el resto los deja